# Crop image in flex using a non-rectangular shape

Tags: apache-flex, image, crop

I've been following this tutorial to crop images in flex: http://code.mediablur.com/ImageCropper/ImageCropperDemo.html.

At the heart of its cropping is using a method called "copyPixels".  However, this method takes as one of its arguments a rectangular shape for its crop region.  Are there other strategies I can use to crop it not using a rectangle.

I am going after letting the user specify the region that should be cropped using a series of points.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting image has to be a rectangle, of course, but you can mask with transparency using [`BitmapData.draw`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) and [`BlendMode`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BlendMode.html):

```
var originalImage:BitmapData; // defined
var maskPath:GraphicsPath; // defined

var maskShape:Shape = new Shape();
maskShape.graphics.beginFill(0, 0); // fill region with transparent
maskShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, originalImage.width, originalImage.height);
maskShape.graphics.endFill();

maskShape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
maskShape.graphics.drawPath(maskPath.commands, maskPath.data, maskPath.winding);
maskShape.graphics.endFill();

var resultImage:BitmapData = originalImage.clone();
resultImage.draw(maskShape, null, null, BlendMode.ALPHA);
```

For cropping, you would probably do something more fancy in the last few lines--copying a region instead of cloning the whole `originalImage`, and/or applying a transform when applying the `maskShape`.

(I believe it's necessary to use a `DisplayObject` to use `BlendMode`s, but that's not clear in the documentation.)